# loginctl lock-session does not lock screen on ubuntu-mate 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lock-screen, ubuntu-mate

I was trying to follow some guide for locking the screen after suspend which is practically to create a service is triggered by `sleep.target`. It did not work for me.

I believe this is due to the fact that the main command of my service is: `/bin/loginctl lock-sessions` which does not seem to lock anything.

This means **when I try:**

```
/bin/loginctl lock-sessions
```

it does not lock my screen.

Why the above happens? How can I lock my screen by executing a command?

**Note:** I redirected `ps aux` both while on locked screen and while not. The main difference I spotted was: the following two extra processes running (when screen lock was active):

```
/usr/lib/mate-screensaver/mate-screensaver/floaters /usr/share/pixmaps/mate-logo-white.svg
/usr/lib/mate-screensaver/mate-screensaver-dialog --status-message= --enable-switch
```

However even if I execute them both manually I do not enter the lock sceen state.

Comment: I have this strange problem too after suspend/resume for a whole month without reboot my desktop linux PC (also running Ubuntu mate 22.04). After apt update/upgrade and reboot, the loginctl works again.

Answer (score 0):

Which desktop environment do you have aor in any environment you should go to the display settings and see sleep time or something like that because most of the time settings are not correct you should try that

Comment: I use the defaults of ubuntu-mate 22.04 so the desktop environment is [MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_(software)).